# Will the magnitude of velocity change in uniform circular motion?

Tags: kinematics

I came across a question: A particle describes uniform circular motion in a circle of radius $$2m$$, with angular speed of $$2rads^{-1}.$$The magnitude change in its velocity in $$\frac{\pi}{2}$$sec is-----
In a circular motion, the velocity of a particle changes only direction. Whether the change in direction changes the magnitude of velocity?

Comment: Only change in direction will not change magnitude . However , it is not clearly understood from your question...

Comment: By definition, velocity does not change in uniform circular motion. You technically don't even need a physical reason why. It is just a definition. If you want to understand the physics of uniform circular motion then I suggest rewording your question.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of velocity is the *speed* of the object. In *uniform circular motion*, there is just the centripetal force and that *just changes the direction of the velocity and not the speed* (if the speed has to change, then there has to be a tangential acceleration, and then it would be *non uniform circular motion*).

The question you showed has an answer of $0$ because the ***magnitude of velocity i.e. speed is not changing, only direction is changing***.

Cheers!!